# Why my service its not being correctly declared?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments

Im creating a Payment Service for my app with Stripe. I have:

```
#app/services/service_error.rb

class PaymentGateway::ServiceError < StandardError
  attr_reader :exception_message

  def initialize(message, exception_message: )
    # Call the parent's constructor to set the message
    super(message)

    # Store the exception_message in an instance variable
    @exception_message = exception_message
  end
end

class PaymentGateway::CreateSubscriptionServiceError < PaymentGateway::ServiceError
end
```

And in my controller im trying to run it:

```
#app/controller/subscriptions_controller.rb

class SubscriptionsController < ApplicationController
  rescue_from PaymentGateway::CreateSubscriptionServiceError do |e|
    redirect_to root_path, alert: e.message
  end
```

When I run my code Im getting this error:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (uninitialized constant PaymentGateway::CreateSubscriptionServiceError):
```

What im doing wrong here?

Comment: What's your Rails version?

Comment: Its Rails 5.1.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct paths will look like this:

```
# app/services/payment_gateway/service_error.rb
class PaymentGateway::ServiceError < StandardError
end

# app/services/payment_gateway/create_subscription_service_error.rb
class PaymentGateway::CreateSubscriptionServiceError < PaymentGateway::ServiceError
end
```

ActiveSupport should be able to load classes correctly then.