# Problems with naming conventions in services

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am following [this guide](https://reinteractive.com/posts/357-managing-stripe-subscription-payments-in-rails) to implement a Stripe Payment Service, but I get an uninitialized constant error.

The article sometimes uses a path without underscore  like `paymentgateway` that corresponds to a class in snake case:

```
app/services/paymentgateway/stripeclient.rb

class PaymentGateway::StripeClient
  def lookup_customer(identifier: )
    handle_client_error do
      @lookup_customer ||= Stripe::Customer.retreive(identifier)
    end
  end
```

and other times uses an underscored path like this:

```
app/services/payment_gateway/client.rb

class PaymentGateway::Client
  attr_accessor :external_client

  def initialize(external_client: PaymentGateway::StripeClient.new)
    @external_client = external_client
  end
```

Is this a typographical error on the article? I did not find in any mentioning in the Ruby on Rails Guide on how to use this. What is the right way to follow the naming conventions on those cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use underscore and modules for namespace.

suppose if ur path is like this `app/services/payment_gateway/stripe_client.rb`, then

```
module PaymentGateway
  class StripeClient
    def lookup_customer(identifier: )
      handle_client_error do
        @lookup_customer ||= Stripe::Customer.retreive(identifier)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The convention is to use underscores. The correct path would be

```
app/services/payment_gateway/stripe_client.rb
```

Comment: I did exactly like this Marcin. And it is giving this error on that case: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52599337/why-my-service-its-not-being-correctly-declared